# Ruby on Rails - Mass assignment issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, mass-assignment

Begginer Running rails 3.2.2, Ruby 1.8.7

I have 2 models, a Hotel (created by scaffolding) and Facility (with empty controller).
I am able to set the 1-to-1 association and siplaying fields but can't seem to insert it in the databases.
Im getting:

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in HotelsController#create
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: @hotel
app/controllers/hotels_controller.rb:48:in 'new'
app/controllers/hotels_controller.rb:48:in 'create'
```

--> My models are:

```
class Hotel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :facility, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :facility, :allow_destroy => true
  attr_accessible :name, :rating, :recommended, :facility_attributes
end

class Facility < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :hotel
  attr_accessible :concierge, :hotel_id, :room24h
end
```

My facility controller, as I said, is empty (it can be, right? since im associating with Hotel?)
My hotel_controller is the default after creating scaffolding, only with 1 added line:

```
 def new
    @hotel = Hotel.new
    @hotel.build_facility  #-->I added this only, I searched and all i found was this

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @hotel }
    end
  end

 def create
    @hotel = Hotel.new(params[:hotel])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @hotel.save
        format.html { redirect_to @hotel, :notice => 'Hotel was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :json => @hotel, :status => :created, :location => @hotel }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.json { render :json => @hotel.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Finaly, my form html is:

```
<%= form_for(@hotel) do |f| %>

<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :rating %><br />
    <%= f.number_field :rating %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :recommended %><br />
    <%= f.check_box :recommended %>
  </div>
  <br />

    <h2>Hotel Facilities</h2>

    <%= f.fields_for :@hotel do |facility_fields| %>
 <div class="field">
    <%= facility_fields.label :room24h, "24h Room Service:" %>
    <%= facility_fields.check_box :room24h %>
  </div>
 <div class="field">
    <%= facility_fields.label "Concierge:" %>
    <%= facility_fields.check_box :concierge %>
  </div>
<%end%>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The error I am getting when creating is at beggining of question. Should I be adding more code do the hotel_controller? What could it be? Also, what more code would i have to do for the editing/updating?

Thanks in advance and sorry, im new at RoR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I lot of time has passed, I changed the relation to a HABTM, altered the model and controller and it worked.
I believe it was due to it being a has_one relation. It needed to be a N-N relationship.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
attr_accessible :concierge, :hotel_id, :room24h
```

to

```
attr_accessible :concierge, :hotel_id, :room24h, :hotel
```

in `Facility`